# Converting decimal to binary in java having trouble with reversing order

Tags: java, binary, decimal

Hey so I'm taking my first cs course ever at my university its taught in java. I'm having trouble converting decimal to binary. I seem to be able to get the correct output but its in reverse order, and I have no idea how to put it in the correct order, here is what I've coded so far,

```
import java.util.*;
public class lab6 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a decimal number to convert to binary: ");
   int x = input.nextInt();
   int y;
   String y1="";
   while(x!=0){
       y=x%2;
       x=x/2;
       y1 = Integer.toString(y);
       System.out.print(y1+" ");
     }    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are showing the output in correct order only. But if you want to reverse the current output you can use below code:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a decimal number to convert to binary: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y;
        String y1="";
        String reverse = "";
        while(x!=0){
           y=x%2;
           x=x/2;
           y1 = Integer.toString(y);
         //  System.out.print(y1+" ");
           reverse = y1+" "+reverse;
         }          
        System.out.println("Reverse Order :"+reverse);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the digits in some container(e.g. `ArrayList`) and then iterate it back to front printing each digit as you iterate.

Answer (score 0):

For adding to Ivaylo answer, you can also store it in a `StringBuilder` and reverse it using [reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method.