# java convert decimal to any binary bit

Tags: java, converters

I'm making a project of converting decimal number into binary. But I have a problem that how can I convert any entered number into binary (I'm using array), here is my code:

```
    public void Decimal2Binary(int a)
{
    int result []=new int[8];
    for (int i = 7;i >=0; i--,a/=2) {
        result[i]=a%2;
}
```

I do not need it for just only 8-bit binary result, yet, I need it for any size.

Comment: Why don't you pass it as an argument?

Comment: `Integer.toBinaryString()`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784630/converting-decimal-to-binary-java?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147413/convert-decimal-to-binary?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008606/converting-decimal-to-binary-in-java-having-trouble-with-reversing-order?rq=1 , and (apart from that) not very clear.

Comment: Any size makes absolutely no sense in a strongly typed language where the primitive types are strictly defined by the JLS.

Comment: There is no decimal here. Everything is already in binary. What you are really doing is separating the bits.

Answer (score 0):

use this function Integer.toBinaryString(int)...
and why do you want it to be in a array ?
can't it be an array list or big decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually specify the output, but here goes.

assuming unsigned (as it looks like you have).

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while(a > 0) {
    result.append(a % 2);
    a = a / 2; // This will round down automatically. ;)
}
```

If you need to handle negative numbers, I would do bitwise comparisons using the & operator - you could also use >> for the division, but I am leaving that optimisation for the compiler to keep the source more readable.

*obviously you could change that to any form of append*

Comment: if you actually want it as a string output, I would suggest using the standard functionality, but if you want to control the bits in whatever forms you get them this gives you that control.